# React-Redux - Update state, based on state property change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to make changes to a state property each time another property changes.

For example:

- when `counter` changes, I need to make an update to the `peopleArray`
- multiple actions change `counter` (See the Dispatcher block)

State:

```
{
  peopleArray: ['Shawn', 'Amanda', 'Jermaine']
  foodArray: []
  counter: 0
}
```

Dispatcher:

```
onAddPeople: (name) => ({ type: 'ADD_PEOPLE', payload: name }) // increments counter
onAddFood: (type) => ({ type: 'ADD_FOOD', payload: type }) // increments counter
```

(Part) of Reducer: ***increments counter*** each time a new person is added

```
if (action.type === 'ADD_PEOPLE') {
  let updatePeople = [...state.peopleArray]
  updatedPeople.push(action.payload.name)
  return {
    ...state,
    peopleArray: updatedPeople,
    counter: counter + 1
  }
}
```

Basically I want some some sort of subscriber, which will allow me to trigger an update to the `peopleArray`, but I don't want to end up in an infinite loop.

I have tried the following in a PeopleComponent.js file:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps: any) {
    if (this.props.counter !== nextProps.counter) {
        // Trigger update to peopleArray
    }
}
```

The problem is, once I trigger the update in `componentWillUpdate`, the `peopleArray` changes, which makes the state change... which re-renders the app and calls `componentWillUpdate` again.... enter **infinite loop**   :(

How do I do this "properly"?

Comment: So when the counter increments you want to update the people array or the vice versa?

Comment: Yes I would like to update the people array when counter increases

Answer (score 0):

should just be able to use `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.counter !== this.props.counter) {
        // update component state accordingly
    }
}
```

`componentWillUpdate` is deprecated and is [completely not advised](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate) to alter state within it for the reasons you describe. However, `componentDidUpdate` is safe to alter state:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop. It would also cause an extra re-rendering which, while not visible to the user, can affect the component performance.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

I am not convinced at this point this implementation will cause an infinite loop. If the OP does a console.log test from inside the condition within `componentDidUpdate()` there shouldn't be unnecessary state changes being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reconsider your design. Actions are the only things that should update the redux state, so if ADD_PEOPLE needs to update the counter besides adding people, then that action should do so (as you noted).

Conversely, there may be an action called INCREASE_COUNTER which also needs to add people.

Triggering actions in `componentWillUpdate` is poor design and I strongly recommend against trying something like that.

The reason is that Redux is *not* just an event framework. Actions are strictly reserved for external interaction between the application and external data sources (most commonly user interaction and requests to servers).

Comment: Each time "something happens", the count is increased. That means, adding people, adding food, deleting people, deleting food, etc. That is why `counter` is its own state property. Does react-redux not have a straightforward way to do-something, when a state-property changes?

Comment: The basic principle behind React is that it uses unidirectional data flow, in this case:
action -> redux -> react components. If you want something done when an action is dispatched, do that in redux. The word "state-property" is unclear - are you referring to a React prop that is connected to redux?